# How to ignore @OneToMany relation for GET request?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity called Restaurant, and it has Set of objects of another class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private Set<Meal> meals = Collections.emptySet();
    //getters, setters and other variables
}
```

Class "Meal" has `@ManyToOne` relation to the "Restaurant".

I have Spring JPA repository:

```
@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Integer> {
}
```

When I use `findById()` method - I'm getting a restaurant with it's meals
[image]

I need to get a Restaurant WITHOUT any meals. Set must not be taken from repository - it should be ignored
How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set data will not be taken since your configuration is:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
```

Lazy means that data will not be fetch if you don't ask it explicitly.

When you evaluate expression and click on meals it will execute query (because it will call get method) which will return data.
You can try this if you turn on show_sql flag using:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Additional, try to return data without debugging it.

Also, use DTO to return data to the client and don't use @JsonIgnore, it is bad practice (it is quick solution)

Comment: Is it possible to select without using Lazy on the entity? In case there is specific cases

Answer (score 2):

You can add `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the attribute or create a DTO which holds only the attributes that you need from the model.

Comment: As I know - that Set will be got from the Repository anyway, but it will be ignored for a view

Comment: I need to ignore that field in a data which was got from Repository

Comment: If by ignoring it you mean DON'T NEED IT , you can use a DTO object which will have only the attributes that you want.
For example : 
MealModel mealModel = repository.findMeal();
MealDTO mealDTO = new MealDTO();
mealDTO.setAttribute(mealDTO.getAttribute());
mealDTO.setAttributeTwo(mealDTO.getAttributeTwo());

Comment: Set<Meals> must not be taken from repository - it should be ignored!

Comment: The findById() method returns an Optional type which will eventually call the "getMeals()" method with reflection so the Set<Meal> will be filled. Try use the findById().get() instead only for debugging to see the results.